# No exceptions caught from faulted CountinueWith supplied with async delegate

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

The following program which I'd like to catch exceptions that I think should occur when accessing t.Result

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () => await Test()).Wait();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task Test()
    {
        var t1 = Task.Run<int>(() => { throw new Exception("1"); return 1; });
        var tasks = new[]
            {
                //t1.ContinueWith(t => {
                //    var y = t.Result + 1;
                //    }),
                //t1.ContinueWith(t => {
                //    var y = t.Result + 1;
                //    })
                t1.ContinueWith(async t =>
                {
                    var y = t.Result + 1;
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                }),
                t1.ContinueWith(async t =>
                {
                    var y = t.Result + 1;
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                }),
            };
        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught");
        }
    }
}
```

But exceptions are not caught if I use async delegates. Both tasks are faulted, but their exceptions are null.

Questions

1. What is the trick and where can I read more details?
2. If I lose awaiting in some way, can I be sure continuations are completed after Task.WhenAll returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion arises from the difference in intended usage of `Task.Run` versus `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.ContinueWith`.

[`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx), through its overloads, can accept either a synchronous delegate (`Action` or `Func<TResult>`), or an asynchronous delegate (`Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<TResult>>`). If asynchronous delegates are specified, `Task.Run` takes care of unwrapping the inner task representing the asynchronous operation, and returning *that* as the result.

[`Task.ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx), on the other hand, does not recognize asynchronous delegates. If you pass a `Func<Task, Task>` delegate to [`ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx), it will simply wrap the asynchronous operation within its own outer task, returning `Task<Task>` as the result. (Same applies to [`TaskFactory.StartNew`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew(v=vs.110).aspx).) Therefore, your `Task.WhenAll` would only be waiting for the outer tasks, not the asynchronous operations. This is not what you want.

To unwrap the inner asynchronous operation, you can simply call `Unwrap`:

```
t1.ContinueWith(async t =>
{
    var y = t.Result + 1;
    await Task.Delay(100);
}).Unwrap(),
```

For a discussion of this issue, see [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/). (The handling of asynchronous delegates in `ContinueWith` is similar to `StartNew`.) For the rationale behind unwrapping, see [How to: Unwrap a Nested Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-unwrap-a-nested-task).

Also, I would suggest that you avoid mixing `await` and `ContinueWith`. In your case, you could await the result of `t1` within an asynchronous delegate, rather than registering a continuation to it. You will need a self-invoking anonymous function to do this in a single method…

```
((Func<Task>)(async () => 
{
    var y = await t1 + 1;
    await Task.Delay(100);
}))(),
```

…but it becomes clearer to read if you split it out into a separate method:

```
private static async Task Test()
{
    var t1 = Task.Run<int>(() => { throw new Exception("1"); return 1; });
    var tasks = new[]
    {
        IncrementAndDelayAsync(t1),
        IncrementAndDelayAsync(t1),
    };
    // ...
}

private static async Task IncrementAndDelayAsync(Task<int> t1)
{
    var y = await t1 + 1;
    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I should look at return type to guess..